# Setup - KVM + HP Docking Station + 2 HP Business Laptops + Monitor + Keyboard + Mouse

Tags: laptop, kvm-switch, docking-station

I already running HP Elite Laptop in a HP Docking station connected with Additional monitor.
I need to enhance the setup by connecting my second laptop, such that I can control it from same keyboard, mouse while i have it's display in either in the monitor or my first laptop. I know KVM could be used to share input peripherals but not sure how everything connected via docking station.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a KVM between your keyboard, mouse, and monitor and the docking station and the other laptop. Basically, for purposes of setting up the KVM switch, you would pretend that the docking station is the computer itself (ignore that it's actually a dock). This would allow you to switch the external monitor, keyboard, and mouse between the two devices.

Note that you might want to look in to [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), this would allow you to control both computers very easily, but you wouldn't be able to switch the monitor between the two (Synergy just handles control, not video).

Comment: Right, KVM will go between those connections on the docking station and your actual keyboard/monitor/mouse.

Comment: My docking staton already has connections to PS2 Keyboard, USB Mouse and DVI Monitor. It still has not occupied USBs and PS2s. So the final setup would be, I connect docking station to KVM, (both mouse & keyboard connector from KVM device 1 will connect to non occupied docking points), where to connect video in for KVM device 1?                                                                          Also, my second laptop, Can I connect it to KVM directly? I could connect Video (and configure windows to have 2 Monitors), what about the mouse and keyboard ?

Comment: I see where you're confused now. You would connect the PS/2 and DVI connections on your docking station to one output of the KVM, and the other laptop to the other output. Your mouse/keyboard/monitor would then connect to the KVM input.

Comment: thanks almost clarified, what's about my additional monitor ? Aslo I found following gadget from IOGear, that could be really useful.... http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS661U/ ..so i could keep the existing setup while connect two laptops via USB

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:
[2Port DVI KVM-Switch](http://global.level1.com/Desktop-KVM-Switches/KVM-0260/p-505.htm)

Your Keyboard,Mouse and external Monitor is connected to the Base. From This base two cable loomes are lead through. One is connected to the Docking Station and the other to the second Notebook.

Please read the whitepapers carefully. The most know problem is, that you have to restart after a new setup. (I'm not really sure if this is necessary while using two hosts)